# Magento 2.2 Sending multiple order confirmation emails

Tags: magento2, order-email, smtp

Over the last couple of days our Magento 2.2 instance has been sending multiple copies of order confirmation emails to the customer. Sometimes as many as 10 identical emails received. Has anyone else experienced this, and ultimately found an answer?
We are using **Swissup FireCheckout** and **MagePlaza SMTP** module if that helps.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, we are also facing the same problem. This happens some times only, not every order.

Comment: Are you all using smtp extension?

Comment: @DominicXigen, Yes I'm using **MagePal GmailSmtpApp**?????????

Comment: write any custom code for sending email ???

Comment: I think, in our case this was actually caused by overrunning cron jobs. We had a cron job that was taking an excessively long time to run, and resulting in multiple duplicate cron jobs being scheduled to run at the same time. I believe this to have been the cause, fixing the long running job and clearing the duplicated jobs in the scheduler seems to have cured in our case.